# Excel VBA - combine macro to rename worksheet & macro to merge worksheets in one macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am using two macro's. 
The first macro to rename the worksheet of excel files to the name of the workbook. And the second macro to merge these renamed workbooks (only containing one worksheet) into one workbook. Each renamed workbook is a separate tab in the new workbook that is created by the second macro.

Example of a name of one of the files: AA_aaa##123456789-123456789.
In the rename macro I remove the last characters from the name so the worksheet is named AA_aaa. All files have different names, but all with the same format and length.

For the first macro I open each excel file, run the macro and close and save the excel file again. For the second macro I open an exmpy excel file only containing the merge macro. I run the merge macro from this file and it asks me to select the files I want to merge. The files that I want to merge need to be closed at that time.

The order of the steps that I take is:
1. I open the excel file for which I want to rename the worksheet.
2. I run the rename macro (I have another excel open that contains the macro to rename so I can select it from there).
3. I save and close the workbook with the renamed worksheet.
4. I do the same for all other excel files (I usually have around files 10 to rename at once).
5. I open an Excel file that contains the merge macro (there is no data in the excel file).
6. I run the merge macro.
7. The macro asks me to select the files I want to merge (these are the 10 files I renamed in the previous steps).
8. I select the files renamed in my first steps.

Result: I now have one file with multiple worksheets, these worksheets contain the data which was in the files I renamed, the name of each worksheet is the name of the original file!

I need to do this process about 20 times per day. Especially step 1 (renaming the worksheets) is taking a lot of time because I need to open and save each file separately. I was hoping that someone can help me combining these two macro's into one. The aim is to run 1 macro that first renames the worksheets and then merges them into one file.

These are the macro's I currently use:

**Macro 1 to rename the worksheets:**

```
Sub RenameSheet()
Dim myname
myname = Replace(ActiveWorkbook. Name, ".xls", "")
    ActiveSheet.Select
    Activesheet.Name = Left$(Activeworkbook.Name, InStrRev(Activeworkbook.Name,".")-22)
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

**Macro 2 to merge workbooks:**

```
Sub MergeExcelFiles()
    Dim fnameList, fnameCurFile As Variant
    Dim countFiles, countSheets As Integer
    Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wbkCurBook, wbkSrcBook As Workbook

    fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)

    If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then

        If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
            countFiles = 0
            countSheets = 0

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

            Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook

            For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
                countFiles = countFiles + 1

                Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)

                For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                    countSheets = countSheets + 1
                    wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
                Next

                wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

            Next

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

            MsgBox "Processed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox "No files selected", Title:="Merge Excel files"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean *"to save time while executing them"*? Combining these two macros will be practically no performance issue at all. Do you mean saving you time from having to go to your menu of macros and select run on both?

Comment: At this moment I get on a daily basis around 100 excelfiles. For all these files I first rename the worksheet to the name of the workbook. I then use the merge excel files macro to merge them together. This second step goes really fast, but for the first one I open each file, run the macro, then close it and go to the next. This is what is taking a lot of time. I hoped I could somehow do that renaming while executing the second macro.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of merging the macros, you could keep them separate and just call them together from one:

```
Sub RunMyMacros()

RenameSheet
MergeExcelFiles

End Sub
```

In your case, I think this would be the cleanest solution. Merging them won't improve performance.

If you *really* need them combined, I suppose it would look like this - note, I've made a couple comments on some lines which are essentially useless:

```
Sub MergeExcelFiles()
    Dim fnameList, fnameCurFile As Variant
    Dim countFiles, countSheets As Integer
    Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wbkCurBook, wbkSrcBook As Workbook
    Dim myname

    'Rename sheet
    myname = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xls", "")
    'ActiveSheet.Select     'this serves no purpose
    ActiveSheet.Name = Left$(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 22)
    Range("A1").Select 'I don't think this does anything for you either

    'Merge excel files
    fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)

    If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then

        If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
            countFiles = 0
            countSheets = 0

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

            Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook

            For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
                countFiles = countFiles + 1

                Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)

                For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                    countSheets = countSheets + 1
                    wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
                Next

                wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

            Next

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

            MsgBox "Processed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox "No files selected", Title:="Merge Excel files"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this, but I receive Run-time error '5'.

Comment: I assume I receive that error because for the rename macro I need to have the workbook open and for the second macro I need to run it without the files which I want to merge open. To run the second macro, I open a new excel file and run it from there. While running the macro I select the files I need to merge.

Comment: It's hard to tell what workbook you're working from when you use `ActiveWorkbook` - What order do you run these macros in?

Comment: The order is: 1. I open the excel file for which I want to rename the worksheet. 2. I run the rename macro. 3. I save and close the file. 4. I do the same for all other files. 5. I open an Excel file that contains the merge macro (the file itself is empty). 6. I run the merge macro 7. The macro asks me to select the files I want to merge 8. I select the files renamed in my first steps. Result: I now have one file with multiple worksheets, these worksheets contain the data which was in the files I renamed, the name of each worksheet is the name of the original file! I hope it makes sense now...

Comment: *"I do the same for all other files"* What other files? How many others are there? What are there current names, and are they always named this? Is the rename macro located in each workbook, or is that ran from your `PERSONAL.xlsb` or another workbook? Lots of questions to be answered here - I'd suggest maybe editing your question with these details or re-posting it altogether and explains these steps just like you have here.

Comment: Just edited my question with the details. Please let me know if you need more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

After quite some trial and error I managed to combine the two macro's. I found a similar question on here and used one of the answers and changed it to my needs.

I added this to the MergeExcelFiles macro:

```
wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count).Name = Left$(wbkSrcBook.Name, InStrRev(wbkSrcBook.Name, ".") - 22)
```

The files are now renamed while executing the macro to merge the files:

```
Sub MergeAndRenameExcelFiles()
Dim fnameList, fnameCurFile As Variant
Dim countFiles, countSheets As Integer
Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
Dim wbkCurBook, wbkSrcBook As Workbook

fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)

If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then

    If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
        countFiles = 0
        countSheets = 0

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook

        For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
            countFiles = countFiles + 1

            Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)

            For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                countSheets = countSheets + 1
                wksCurSheet.Copy After:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
                wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count).Name = Left$(wbkSrcBook.Name, InStrRev(wbkSrcBook.Name, ".") - 22)
            Next

            wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

        Next

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

        MsgBox "Procesed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
    End If

Else
    MsgBox "No files selected", Title:="Merge Excel files"
End If
```

End Sub